# how can I send post data in php programatically?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I need to send post data to another page programatically.
I have 2 DateTime in Database I want to compare these DateTimes. and if one of them is bigger than another automatically send post data to another page.

this is simple code:

```
require('connect.php');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM POSTS ORDER BY POSTDATETIME ASC';

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows>0)
{
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo $row["ID"].".".$row["PostDateTime"]."<br/>";
        $text = $row["Text"];

        $d = new DateTime("now");
        $d1 = new DateTime($row["PostDateTime"]);
        if($d>$d1)
            {
                // Send Post Data to another page;

            }
        else
            {
                echo "false<br/>";
            }
    }
}
```

I googled but there is no way to send automatically post data without any form or ajax . 
ajax needs to some event occurs. 
And I don't have any Idea how to do that . I will appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CURL to send a post request.

```
require('connect.php');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM POSTS ORDER BY POSTDATETIME ASC';

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows>0)
{
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo $row["ID"].".".$row["PostDateTime"]."<br/>";
        $text = $row["Text"];

        $d = new DateTime("now");
        $d1 = new DateTime($row["PostDateTime"]);
        if($d>$d1)
        {
            $ch = curl_init('http://www.linktoyourotherpage.com');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $row);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "false<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve what you're doing is with a intermediate page that sends the user to Page C. Here's a small/simple snippet on how you can achieve that:

```
<?php
 if($d>$d1) { ?>
<form id="myForm" action="Page_C.php" method="post">
<?php
    foreach ($_POST as $a => $b) {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="'.htmlentities($a).'" value="'.htmlentities($b).'">';
    }
?>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
</script>
<?php } else {
            echo "false<br/>";
      }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

store the data in a global variable say for example $_SESSION and redirect to another page ... session start and use the global variable.